# Python Script is using all my RAM - is there a way to reset?

Tags: python, memory, ram

I have been working on an MMO bot for fun and the script itself stores previous data points of where my character was to continue on the script. After a few hours I came back to my machine giving a memory error and nothing working on the computer forcing me to need a restart. Is there any sort of command that I can give to the script that would reset the memory its cached up?

With the bot, I dont need to keep this memory cached up for more than a few seconds or even minutes at most, the stored up data does nothing for me. I was wondering if anyone had a way to fresh wipe the stored memory after a given time and start fresh?

Comment: There is no generic answer, you need to provide your code, it is your code that is storing data without need, so changes there would need to be made.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this script:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["purge"])
```